# cocos2dx http request on a network with proxy

Tags: http, url, cocos2d-x, http-proxy

I am trying to hit a url on amazon server using cchttpclient. But my network has proxy and the request is not completed. The http response code received is 500 which is for uncomplete request.
The piece of code is given below .

```
cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest* request = new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();
request->setUrl("http://www.httpbin.org/get");
request->setRequestType(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(HttpClientTest::onHttpRequestCompleted));
request->setTag("GET test1");
cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
request->release();
```

Comment: I'm not an expert but usually to use connections via proxy first you should connect to proxy, send a 'CONNECT' message with target host; proxy will establish connection and return you data.

Comment: You are right.. But can you suggest how to do that.. Or any tutorial link